# base_url() is not working in CodeIgniter 3.0

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have configured CI3 in my localhost,

I have followed all the steps to work with CI
1) Opened routes and set it to `$route['default_controller'] = 'login';`
2)In config.php settings are....

```
`$config['base_url'] = '';
`$config['index_page'] = '';
`$config['uri_protocol']= 'REQUEST_URI';`
```

3)url helper included in autoload.php

So,there is no scope of any CI error and it works fine totally...
My only concern is when i use base_url() to include files and call it the output provided is "http://::1/project_name/"

So,why it is not providing proper path exactly?

Comment: You need to set the base url in config.php file..

Answer (score 1):

Your `$config['base_url']` is not defined in `config.php`. Define as:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/yourcms/';
```

Comment: i think there is no such a need to define it because it takes the base_url as per the environment changes like localhost OR any LIVE PATH..If i am not wrong!

Comment: no for local environment you need to pass it, otherwise u need check if Environment is localhost else production....

Comment: @Kunal  i always use this: $config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

Comment: @Kunal: and always use this for production, $config['base_url'] = "http://".str_replace("http://", "", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

Comment: @Kunal: one more suggestion you can define your ENVIRONMENT in index.php

Answer (score 0):

Before using base_url() in CI. You have to first edit config.php file with

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/Myproject/';
```

In this case i have used localhost:8080, which is my port number for server.